# How do I set the build path for E-P-I-C in Eclipse Galileo?

Tags: eclipse, perl, ide, build, path

I have E-P-I-C installed on Eclipse Galileo. When I go to run a Perl script nothing happens because I don't believe is any connection from Eclipse to the Perl SDK (is that the right term? I don't know if it is different because it's Perl).

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with `C:\Perl\bin`

If I click on Perl E-P-I-C project and click on properties I can then see 
Perl include Path. I have added the above but it didn't change anything.

What this comes down to is: How do I set up the build path for Perl in Eclipse Galileo?

Comment: What kind of distribution do You use? Guessing it's a windows ActiveState and strawberry come in mind omitting cygwin since installation is not that easy.

Comment: Yes, it is windows activeState.

Comment: Two possibilities: 1) add the path to %PATH% and eclipse will find it 2) set path to the perl/wperl.exe using the menu as described in my answer. If EPIC has problems with your (w)perl.exe it will complain at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, the PerlDistribution asks to be added to your %PATH%. For me it added `D:\strawberry\c\bin` and `D:\strawberry\perl\bin`. My Eclipse Galileo uses that environment variable out of the box.

You can set the perl executable for a `.pl` file using Window->Preferences->Perl EPIC and use the File Selector. Works for me with strawberry and standard cywin perl. The perl version shipped with MsysGit seems like it can't handle EPIC breakpoints. Haven't tested with ActiveState Perl so far.

Comment: I've done as you suggested. Thanks, but the file still won't "run". I will admit that I'm not too familiar with pearl. I'm sure you need more information than this to help me but for now I'm just gonna ask. Do I need to set up a run configuration?

Comment: Pearl?! that's a completely different language ;-) Have you tried running your script from command line? What do you expect should happen? Usually a Console Tab comes up and shows the (eventual) output. try: `print $] . "\n";` as shown on [ideone](https://ideone.com/BznxP)

Comment: Got it, thanks alot. I posted what I missed in kb's comments. thanks for reminding me to use the .pl extension.

Answer (score 1):

Vista user here. I have Activestate Perl and it also installed into c:\perl5.10, and added the executable to the %PATH%.

Thus, In my Window/Prefrences/Perl EPIC Menu, the executable is called "perl". No .exe, no absolute path. E-P-i-C has probably found it by searching in the default install locations.

In eclipse, you need to run your perl script once using a right mouse click "run as ...perl local". 
THen this script shows up in the Menu "Run > Run configurations." For simple scripts, the default values in the tab dialogs are all ok (most are empty). Output is written to the console window. Make it visible using Menu Window > View > Console.

Does your perl script generate any output?

Perl Debugging from Eclipse does not work for me either. A dialog box pops up and says I shpuld read the discussion thread for ticket #290... on sourceforge. A very complex matter indeed.

Comment: Got it, I was following your instructions and when I right clicked "run as"-> "perl local" ->"project_name" the file to execute wasn't showing up. I added a .pl to it and it runs. YES!!!